# Python Selenium program terminates after 2~3 hours since it started. It seems like WebSocket Connection Problem. Please teach me

Tags: python, selenium, websocket, terminate, handshake

I am making an automation program using Python Selenium.

The program should be operated 24hours a day.

But whenever I started the program, after 2 hours and 30min, it automatically terminates.

I don't know what the problem is.

But I saw the web socker error presented on 'Chrome Driver Console' and 'Webpage Development Tool Console'.

Please look at the attached image.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: Hi. @DebanjanB. Please see the error logs below and see if you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any error code starting with 5XX indicates a server error and in your case you're getting 502 and 504 errors, which in a nutshell can be summarised as below.

> 502/504 errors usually indicate that a computer, one that the website you're getting the 504 message on doesn't control but relies on, isn't communicating with it quickly enough.

This is likely to be caused by selenium not responding enough. The maximum selenium run time is 1800 seconds (30 minutes) but can be changed `caps['max_duration'] = Integer` to test for longer.

The highest value I believe is 14400 seconds(4 hours) which roughly indicates why you are getting the error. My advice would be to restart the test every 2.30 hours.

Comment: Really? Was the max. time that selenium can play? Does you mean that "official max time is 30min" and "real max time is 4hour" ? right?

Comment: Firstly thank you so much. Secondly, where can I write the phrase - "caps['max_duration'] = 14400" ? Could you show me the example? please~~~~ brother~~~

Comment: My source came from [here](https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/selenium-testing/faq/default-duration-selenium-test-timeout-information/). You are already achieving the maximum test time so setting this variable won't make any difference. What you should do is to restart the test every 2/3 hours if that's possible

Comment: Also, I may be taking this problem in the wrong direction. Can you post your python stack trace when this error occurred? This would help alot

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver/chromedriver.exe') ---------------------------                      
driver.get("http://google.com") ------------------------ where can I add "caps['max_duration'] = 14400" ?

Comment: I only tested with exe files. OK, then I will try with python and check stack trace soon.

Comment: Dear Brother~~ i uploaded the error message from python. please advice if you discover a new problem~~ -------------------------------------------------------- https://pussstudio.blogspot.com/2020/02/loginexercise-0194-70-loginexercise.html

Comment: From my understanding, the error doesn't suggest anything wrong. What I believe is happening is that due to the long-running of the automation it ends up running out of memory, hence the error. My solution would be to set up a cronjob and run the same script every 2 hours or so. This way you're unlikely to get the stackoverflow error since memory will be reallocated at each interval.